# Coverting jquery to plain javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to wean myself off of using jQuery for several items. The below is a trivial example, but I'd like to use it to see how it would be converted to non-jQuery, vanilla javascript:

```
$(function () {

    console.log('jQuery is working.')

    updateBillingSection();

    $('select').on('change', function() {
      updateBillingSection();
    });

    function updateBillingSection() {


        // (1) If the plan is not of type=BUSINESS or INDIVIDUAL, hide the billing section
        var INDIVIDUAL_PLAN = "INDIVIDUAL";
        var BUSINESS_PLAN = 'BUSINESS'
        var paidPlans = [INDIVIDUAL_PLAN, BUSINESS_PLAN]

        var planType = $('select[name="plan_type"] option:selected').val();
        console.log('Plan type: ' + planType);
        if(paidPlans.includes(planType)) {
            $('.paid-plan-details').show("slow");

        } else {
            $('.paid-plan-details').hide("slow");
        }
    }

}
```

My question is two-fold:

- Are there any ways on the above that I can improve the code?
- How would the above be written in javascript, without loading jquery?

Comment: Have a look at http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Shallow googling brings up [this gist](https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/7307312), and it has all the answers. If the problem is knowing Javascript or DOM API, StackOverflow might not be the best place to start; perhaps consider taking a course or reading a book.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To select with CSS selectors like in jquery `$('.paid-plan-details')` becomes `document.querySelector('.paid-plan-details')`

To get the value `$('select[name="plan_type"] option:selected').val()` becomes `document.querySelector('select[name="plan_type"] option:selected').value`

`$('select').on('change', function() {})` becomes `document.querySelector('select').onchange = function() {}`

Some pointers in the right direction. Look at the documentation for all of the details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

Comment: and that fading effect (I'm not sure tho) could be handled using `transition: opacity 0.5s;`

Comment: [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) has a nice example of fading animation - `var s = document.getElementById('thing').style; 
s.opacity = 1; 
(function fade(){(s.opacity-=.1)<0?s.display="none":setTimeout(fade,40)})();`